# How to iterate through a Sequence value in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I'm relatively new to MarkLogic and am using JavaScript. I have a **Sequence** object type below (not a document or XML object type). How can I iterate through it's value, say for example, I want to get the value of *Property2* element under entity?

```
<info>
   <title>Entity</title>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
</info>
<Entity>
    <Property1>100487</Property1>
    <Property2>130008HU52</Property2>
    <Property3/>
    <Property4>Wellhead</Property4>
</Entity >
```

Can you please share a sample code snippet on how to make it work?

Comment: Could you please share code of what you have tried so far? And how did you get your Sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the specific question, a [Sequence](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_59096) is a JavaScript iterable, so if you're working in JavaScript, you can use a `for..of loop` to iterate as shown in:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_59096

```
for (const doc of fn.collection('/my/coll')) {
  // do something with doc
}
```

You can also turn a Sequence into a JavaScript array with the [`toArray()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/Sequence.prototype.toArray) method.

You can then use standard Array methods to iterate, map, or reduce.

If the sequence consists of a single item, you can pass the sequence to [`fn.head()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn.head) to get the item:

```
fn.head(xdmp.arrayValues([1,2,3]))
```

All that said, it's not clear from the question what items are in the sequence.

If the sequence has two Element items (`info` and `Entity`), the loop can use the [`xpath()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/Node.xpath) method on each item to extract subelements.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over sequence and get specific value of sequence based on required criteria. Basic code for you problem is below.

```
let $test := (<info>
 <title>Entity</title>
 <version>0.0.1</version>
</info>,
 <Entity>
  <Property1>100487</Property1>
  <Property2>130008HU52</Property2>
  <Property3/>
  <Property4>Wellhead</Property4>
</Entity >)
return $test[2]/Property2/text()
```